# PostgreSQL return result set of select as json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I would like to have psql return result as json with the following format example:

```json
{
   "2021-10-27" : 324,
   "2021-10-26" : 14,
   "2021-10-28" : 24,
   "2021-10-30" : 4,
}
```

My SQL is :

```
SELECT DATE(user.updated_at), COUNT(*) 
  FROM users AS user
 GROUP BY DATE(user.updated_at)
```

How can I return the above SQL as json.
I use psql version 13.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON_OBJECT_AGG()` function after nesting your current SELECT statement such as

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT_AGG( updated_at, cnt )
  FROM (
        SELECT DATE(updated_at) AS updated_at, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
          FROM users
         GROUP BY DATE(updated_at)
       ) AS u
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=188dbc34407bb4e52b19da19c1245404)</kbd>

Comment: thanks for the reply and the demo!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
json_build_object(
    'current_date', json_agg(users.current_date),
    'current_date', json_agg(users.current_date)
) FROM users
```

Note: "current_date is date values into users table"

Comment: Thanks, but your answer won't get the same result as my sql.
It will present current_date twice as json. The result should be date and a count(grouped by date)